# ASP.NET 4 web forms routing and page resources

Tags: asp.net, localization, routes, globalization, multilingual

I'm creating a ASP.NET 4 web forms application, which is multi-lingual. All is going well, and I've been creating local resource files for each page in the App_LocalResources sub-folder of each application folder and this all works fine.

However I've now added some extra forms which are using routing, and these no longer pickup the resource file.

For example if I have a file /application/project/edit.aspx I would normally place an App_LocalResources folder within the /application/project folder and create edit.aspx.resx etc. However if this page is accessed via a route eg. /application/project/1/edit then the local resource file is no longer used, I guess because the URL doesn't match with the resource file.

Is there any way around this, short of creating resource files in App_GlobalResources for the routed pages? For example can you define which resource files to use for a page in it's code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.

I must be going blind, as I'd actually dropped the resx files for the page into the wrong App_LocalResource folder (a directory level up).

I need sleep...